# Add Selection List from Database using service layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm working on building a website in ASP.NET Core MVC (the latest version).
I have Animals table and Categories table,looking like this:

[image]

I want to get a selection list from the datatbase to the categories (like a dropdown list where you see all the existing categories). I already added some categories to my datatbase.

I have repository and service layer and I wish to use them in my Controller but for some reason it doesnt work- I DONT see any list of categories, only a field to fill. Can anyone tell me why?

The Repository:

```
    public IEnumerable<Category> GetAnimalCategory()
    {
            return _context.Categories;
    }
```

The Service:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<Category>> GetAnimalCategory() => Task.Run(() => _categoryRepository.GetAnimalCategory());
```

The Controller:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    readonly IAnimalService _animalService;
    public AdminController(IAnimalService animalService)
    {
        _animalService = animalService;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAnimal()
    {
        var categories = await _animalService.GetAnimalCategory();
        ViewBag.Categories = categories.Select(c => new SelectListItem(c.Name, c.CategoryId.ToString())).ToList();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost("Create")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAnimal([FromForm] CreateAnimalViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var entity = await _animalService.AddAnimalAsync(vm.Animal, vm.Photo);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**UPDATE-
The View:**

```
<h4>Create New Animal</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="CreateAnimal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Animal.CategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="Animal.CategoryId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CategoryId"></select>
        </div>
```

Comment: View code needs to be included as well

Comment: I've added the View code and changed it - but it still doesnt work . I see an empty dropdown list

Comment: You need to make sure your `ViewBag.Categories` has values,and  use `asp-items="ViewBag.Categories"` as `Dth To Russia` said.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. `asp-items="ViewBag.CategoryId"` should be changed to `asp-items="ViewBag.Categories"`